# Distribution of $Z^\frac{3}{2}$ where $Z$ is the standard normal

Tags: probability-distributions

If $Z$ has a standard normal distribution, then I know that $Z^2$ has a $\chi^2\left(1\right)$ distribution.

My question is whether the variable $Z^\frac{3}{2}$ has a known distribution. What is its name? What is a good resource to read up on its properties? And, especially, does its MGF exist?

Comment: This question is not really at the right level for this site. You might try asking at math.stackexchange.com